# Adding a button with PHP, which could be used for interacting with client side user

Tags: php, button, client, customization

Is it possible adding a button with PHP, which could be used for adding an optional text input field by client side user?

**Purpose:** The client side users could be free creating and adding more and customized variables, which are intended to be used as strings and related or associated variables.

Is It possible to do these kind of tasks simply using PHP alone? Or, should I use some JavaScript like technologies to make those functions available in real world's practices?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible but it would require reloading the page to display the new input fields.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply... I may be good use of that as well if it's needed... I mean, somehow... :)

Comment: You just add if it was possible!

Answer (score 0):

There are AJAX frameworks  for PHP (XAJAX for example, works with XML), but you should definitively use simple Javascript or a framework like jQuery or Prototype for that task. It will require just a few lines of code.

Comment: THANK YOU SO~ MUCH for your help and advices, they're quite valuable actually... :)